# Need to format a list into a numeric object (double)

Tags: r, list, double

I'm trying to use the R0 package in order to estimate this value from a data set. I've formatted my data according to the Example data set, called 'Germany.1918'

```
typeof(Germany.1918)
> [1] "double"
```

So, I know that I need to have my data formatted as 'double' in order to run the package commands.

So far this is what I've done:
- Formatted an excel document in order for it to show exclusively 2 data elements: date and number of cases
- Exported this file as CSV
- Imported this CSV file into R

Here's where I get stuck as the format of the data set Germany.1918 indicates is a double (numeric, I suppose) and otherwise my data is read as such I can't run any calculations.

So, summarizing I need to convert my list into a double R object.

Comment: Providing data helps and suggest look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example . in R, type conversion functions  are generally like `as.` so `as.double` may be what you need. However, R is pretty good at converting (coercing) types automatically.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a `list` and want to convert it into `double`? you can use `as.double(unlist(df$x))` where `df` is your `dataframe` and `x ` is the `variable`.